# Relation between $f_{xx}$ and $f_{yy}$

Tags: partial-derivative

If $f(x,y) = \cos(cx+y) + e^{cx-y}$
Show $f_{xx}=c^{2}f_{yy}$
My try, 
$$f_{x}=-c\sin(cx+y)+ce^{cx-y}$$
$$f_{xx}=-c^{2}\cos(cx+y)+c^{2}e^{cx-y}$$
$$f_{y}=-\sin(cx+y)-e^{cx-y}$$
$$f_{yy}=-\cos(cx+y)+e^{cx-y}$$
So,$$ f_{xx}=c^2(-\cos(cx+y)+e^{cx-y})$$ so,
$$f_{xx}=c^2f_{yy}$$
Is this approach correct?
Is there another approach to show this?

Comment: Your approach is correct and good enough.  I don't think you'll be able to find another approach as direct, efficient, or easy as the one you've already taken.